# React Last input change is not saved in sessionStorage when refresh or changing page like goBack or Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm trying to save the values of my `<from>` in *sessionStorage* so that if the user goes to another page of the website, for instance by clicking on the link to create a new 'Author', when the user goes back to the `<from>` all the values are still there.

But, if I click on a link after putting some values on my `<TextField>` input, every last input of every field is not there when I come back to my form.

eg. I write `hello` on my input if I refresh i have `hell`

Hope it's clear, and someone can enlighten me on what I'm missing, it would be great.
Bellow an extract of my code.

```js
const initialValues = {
  title: '',
  //... and other stuff
}

export default function BookForm() {

  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value) {
      setValues({...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
      sessionStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(values))
    }
    else {
      setValues({...values, [prop]: initialValues[prop]})
      sessionStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(values))
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!isLoaded) {
      loadAutocomplete()
    }
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('values')){
      setValues(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('values')))
    }
  }, [isLoaded])

}

return (
    <form className={classes.root} onSubmit={sendForm}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12}>

          {/*TITRE OK*/}
          <LineForm>
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              name={"title"}
              id="book-title"
              label="TITRE"
              required
              value={values.title}
              onChange={handleChange}
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
            />
          </LineForm>

// ...
```

EDIT:

```
let formValues = {...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value}
    if (event.target.value) {
      setValues(formValues)
      sessionStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(formValues))
    }
```

this seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you a `setState` function is executed, the values of the state don't update immediately, in your case when you do that:

```
      setValues({...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
      sessionStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(values))
```

you set in the session storage the variable `values` but it isn't the most updated one.

Just save the value you send to `setValues` and use that to update the Session Storage.

EDIT:

how it would look:

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value) {
      const newValues = {...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value};

      setValues(newValues)
      sessionStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(newValues))
    }
    else {
      setValues({...values, [prop]: initialValues[prop]})
      sessionStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(values))
    }
  };
```

Comment: ```
let formValues = {...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value}
    if (event.target.value) {
      setValues(formValues)
      sessionStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(formValues))
    }
```
Something like this ?
it actually works

Comment: I'll edit my answer to add a solution @PaulChoppin